# How to capture event triggered by and embedded object using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an old html code that uses an client-hosted dll using java script like this:

```
<OBJECT id="compOCX" height="0" width="0" classid="clsid:D76FC172-8DE8-401E-9179-5890385708F2">
    <PARAM NAME="_StockProps" VALUE="0">
</OBJECT>
```

When functions from this dll are called, it will execute its code and then normally trigger an event that needs to be captured at client-side, like this:

```
<script for=compOCX event=MsrReadOk()>
    getMsrData();
</script>
```

Now, we are trying to migrate to jquery. My question is: how to capture the dll triggered event using classic jquery selectors?

Comment: This pattern is specific to Internet Explorer. jQuery selectors will not help you here.

Comment: By that you mean I can't use jquery or that I shouldn't use jquery?

Comment: By that I mean jQuery (and other libraries) have no portable alternative to the IE-specific `<script for="foo" event="bar">` (see [what are the “for” and “event” attributes of the script tag (Javascript,HTML)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1557446/464709). I wouldn't advise against using jQuery, if anything it will lead you to use less specific markup.