# javascript 'recordnumber' property is not working in iExplorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, recordset

javascript's record number property always returning null.
I have tried with the following code

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" for="myTr" event="onclick">
    alert ("This is the " + this.recordNumber + ". record in the data set.");
</script>
```

```
<b>Click a row in the Table to get its recordNumber!<b>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="2px" border="1px" datasrc="#movies" datapagesize="1" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Jobtitle</th>
            <th>Born</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="myTr">
            <td><span datafld="name"></span></td>
            <td><span datafld="jobtitle"></span></td>
            <td><span datafld="born"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" onclick="myTable.firstPage ()" value="|< First " />
<input type="button" onclick="myTable.previousPage ()" value="< Previous " />
<input type="button" onclick="myTable.nextPage ()" value=" Next >" />
<input type="button" onclick="myTable.lastPage ()" value=" Last >|" />
```

I am trying with iExplorer browser but it is not giving the row number as expected.
reference : http://help.dottoro.com/ljhqpfjc.php#supByObj

Comment: Do you have the code for where `recordNumber` is being set? Also, the scope of `this` will be the global window object, if you didn't know already.

Comment: I believe it will be set on the click event of the tr <tr id="myTr"> and the datasource for the table is an xml file

Comment: You're not using valid HTML. https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT --- The Script element doesn't support `for` nor `event` attributes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557446/what-are-the-for-and-event-attributes-of-the-script-tag-javascript-html and http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html